# Regex pattern for a linear function

Tags: c#, regex

I'm creating a scientific calculator in C#, and I have a collection of linear functions that the user can add entries to. I need to pre-parse a mathematical expression to check for usage of these functions as well as other math functions, track the name of the function and the content in the `(...)`, and replace them with the result of their evaluations.

Take this expression for example:

```
Ans1+(x*2)-(y^3)+abs(z)-avg(x, 5, Ans2)-my2ndFunc(y - (x * 2))
```

I wrote my own regex which I need to match these in the equation:

`abs(z)`
`avg(x, 5, Ans2)`
`my2ndFunc(y - (x * 2))`

I tested it using [Regex Tester v1.5.3](http://www.regextester.com/), but it did not match any items at all. This is the regex I used:

```
\b([a-z][a-z0-9]*)\((..*)\)\b
```

What regular expression would match these functions and store the function name and parameter content? Also, it would cool if someone provided example code on how to do the matches and get the content of the capture groups, but it isn't necessary.

**EDIT**
I don't need the actual mathematical parser, I have [muParser](http://muparser.beltoforion.de/) that implements the shunting yard algorithm. I just need to do a simple search and replace, the math parser takes care of the actual math, I just need the regex to find which parts to evaluate.

**I just need a simple regex that will match:** `myfuncname(any content here)`

Comment: While it's *possible* (albeit unusual, difficult, and non-portable) to do this with regular expressions **in C#**, I would advise against it and instead use a simple parser. This is because mathematical expressions cannot always conform to a regular language. For example, what if one function is nested as the input into another? This is coming from a person who has recently written a scientific calculator application in C#. Trust me. Using a parser, will make it very maintainable.

Comment: @TylerCrompton I have done this before, I used the muParser engine to handle the mathematical equation parsing and wrote my function handling over it in a class. And for the nested functions I simply made the pre-parsing function recursive. But I no longer have the project file for it and I forgot the regular expression I used.

Comment: What happens when you have nesting like abs(avg(x, 5, Ans2))?

Comment: @Rich I make the pre-parsing function recursive. The original regex match doesn't care what is inside the parenthesis of the function, but after it does the match it checks the capture group inside of the function parenthesis to see if it is a function nested inside of the function, if it is it passes that string to the pre-parsing function which evaluates it, returns the result to the top-level function, and then replaces the function call with its result and then evaluates the top-level function. I have done this before, I just cant remember the regex to match: `myfunc(any content here)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I wrote my own regex

I am afraid that you will not get very far with a regex. A wise man once said:

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think
>
> *I know, I'll use regular expressions.*
>
> Now they have two problems.

Checkout [`NCalc`](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/) instead. And if you want to learn more about what's involved in parsing expressions you might checkout the [`following article`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7335/An-extensible-math-expression-parser-with-plug-ins).

And if you want to implement it yourself checkout the [`Shunting-yard algorithm`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm).

---

UPDATE:

Sorry I haven't read your question carefully. You are looking for a regex to only parse input like

```
abs(z) 
avg(x, 5, Ans2) 
my2ndFunc(y - (x * 2))
```

You could use the following:

```
([a-z][a-z0-9]*)\((.+)\)
```

Comment: As you can see from my other comment, I'm not saying regular expressions should be used, but in all fairness, there are perfectly fine scenarios to use regular expressions. For example, using regular expressions in a lexical analyzer is perfectly acceptable to break the text into tokens.

Comment: I don't need the actual mathematical parser, I have muParser that implements the shunting yard algorithm. I just need to do a simple search and replace, the math parser takes care of the actual math, I just need the regex to find which parts to evaluate.

Comment: Even if I was looking to create the actual parser myself the shunting yard algorithm doesn't help me with my function parsing situation at all anyways because it only parses mathematical equations consisting of numbers and operators. I just need a simple regex to match `myfunc(any content here)`

Comment: @BrandonMiller, sorry I haven't read your question carefully. I have updated my answer with an example regular expression you could use to parse the required input.